# Stripe Webhook : No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments, checkout, ngrok

I am trying to integrate a stripe payment method to the project that I am working on but when I try to add the signature checking and "best practices" I get some error while am sure that the signature is correct and compatible with the endpoint secret and the body raw is in the right format here's the code:

```
export const sessionUpdate = async (req, res) => {
  
    const sig = req.headers['stripe-signature'];
    const stripeInstance = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);
  let event;
  const rawBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  // console.log("this is the raw body==>",rawBody); i used these to check the paramters that 
  // console.log("this is the signature", sig); am gonna add to the construct event
 //   console.log(process.env.ENDPOINT_SECRET);
  try {
    event = stripeInstance.webhooks.constructEvent(rawBody, sig, process.env.ENDPOINT_SECRET);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Webhook Error:', err.message);
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
  }

  if (!event || !event.type) {
    console.error('Invalid event data:', event);
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid event data' });
  }

  console.log('Received event:', event.type);
    switch (event.type) {
      case 'checkout.session.completed':
        try {
          const completedEvent = event.data.object;
  
          const { metadata } = completedEvent;
  
          const { post_id } = metadata;
  
          const updatedPost = await Post.findByIdAndUpdate(
            post_id,
            { paymentStatus: true },
            { new: true }
          );
  
          if (!updatedPost) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Post not found' });
          }
  
          return res.json({ message: 'Post status updated successfully', updatedPost });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('Error updating post status:', error);
          return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
        }
  
      default:
        console.log(`Unhandled event type ${event.type}`);
        return res.status(200).end();
    }
  };
```

but i come off with this error :
"Webhook Error: No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?

here is the route

```
router.post(
    "/sessionUpdate",
    express.raw({ type: "application/json" }),
    sessionUpdate
  );
```

Learn more about webhook signing and explore webhook integration examples for various frameworks at [https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing"](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing%22)
i made sure also that the endpoint secret is correct.

I am testing it localy on my pc and i used ngrok to check this out and the stripe cli but still the same problem i get POST /api/user/sessionUpdate   400 Bad Request . I hope that you can help me am really struggling with making it work.

I tried testing the payment using stripe cli and ngrok but both of them are giving me the same result and i tried it without using the event= stripeInstance.webhooks.constructEvent and it worked just fine but while i was reading the documentation of stripe i found out that implementing signature is important

Answer (score 0):

Since `express.raw({ type: "application/json" })` has been set in the route, stringifying the request body is not required. `req.body` can be set directly into `stripeInstance.webhooks.constructEvent`. You may refer to the example code here: https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/quickstart

Comment: yess that's right thank you ,
i found out that the problem is in my app.js file i need to remove the express.json for the webhook function so it won't change the payload type, this the solution i found.
`app.use(
  (
    req: express.Request,
    res: express.Response,
    next: express.NextFunction
  ): void => {
    if (req.originalUrl === '/webhook') {
      next();
    } else {
      express.json()(req, res, next);
    }
  }
);`
thank you for your answer.